# Control Lightning page tab visibility based on profile

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-tab, lightning-page

I have added a new component tab named 'Level' on the lightning page. But i want this tab to be visible only to one specific profile. Is there a workaround to implement this???

[image: Tab]

Comment: Are you adding this tab to a standard lightning page or to a lwc with tabset?

Comment: Its Standard lightning page. This page could be visible to other profiles. But level tab must be visible to only this specific profile along with other tabs on the page.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, it's not possible to hide the tabs conditionally. See the Idea [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003dfmQAA)

You can create a new lightning page and assign it to that profile. In the new lightning page, you can remove the tab not needed for the profile.